# Countdown goes faster at every click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a big problem and can´t solve it:
I make this countdown with NSTimer, the countdown works fine,click a button, the countdown start and when reaches zero a label appear.
The problem comes when I press the button again and the countdown starts again, but this time twice as fast!! and the next time faster and faster... I dont know what to do... I need to make a loop but only works one time... 
Im been searching but I dont find anything about it... don´t know if anybody has the same problem.
Thanx.

```
NSTimer *timer; int i;

-(IBAction)pressButton{
    i = 10;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerFires)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void) timerFires{
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    }
    else{
        label.text = @"Tiempo!!";
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: next time please put some effort into the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably firing the timer multiple times.  You need to cancel the first timer when you click the button the second time.

```
-(IBAction)pressButton{
  i = 10;
  if (timer != nil) {
    [timer invalidate];
  }
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFires)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
  [timer fire];

}
```

Comment: Alternatively, he could disable the button, or change its functionality so that it does cancel (i.e., abort) the first timer w/o starting another countdown.

Comment: Thank you so much... this is what I missing... Also I add disable Button , so when times reach zero, the button are disable. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be bcoz you never stop your timer, so when you click it the second time its as good as 2 timers running and so on....try stopping your timer before you click and start it again..